# Using database jobs in Domain Driven Design

Tags: c#, .net, domain-driven-design

I am creating a .net application using Domain Driven Design approach. The application includes billing clients for services. The rule says that daily, at a given time an invoice should be generated and user's balance should be updated. As I see, the best option here would be a database job which being scheduled does the above task. However, is this compatible with DDD? The logic is split among database and domail layer in this case, which seems not to be a good ideea.

Comment: My problem with your design isn't that you're using database jobs, but that you're already committing to an implementation. At this stage, I don't know that it's necessary to decide how you're going to implement that functionality.

Comment: The ideea of this question was whether DDD accepts putting some part of the implementation into the database. I already designed the model and the corresponding services. Since I am not very experienced in DDD, I asked the question about putting some logic into the DB scripts.

Comment: But why are you jumping to an implementation? How did you decide that "the best option  here would be a database job"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of DDD is managing to decouple domain model from technical concerns as much as possible.

Putting business knowledge in database jobs means:

- You would have 2 places to look for business logic (loss of model isolation)
- Your business logic would be described in 2 languages (e.g. c#; t-sql)
- It might not be easy to manage business logic w/ procedural sql scripts
- It might not be easy to sync w/ part which is written in .Net

I personally wouldn't go that road. I would write background service.

Answer (score 2):

Implementing a database job will be more difficult to debug and unit test if that matters.

I would recommend a service that does scheduled tasks.